# Debug a Mocha test in nativescript

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, mocha.js, nativescript

I would like to be able to debug a Mocha test using VS Code. However, if I run:

`tns test -ios --debug-brk`

I get the error message:

`You cannot use --watch and --debug-brk simultaneously. Remove one of the flags and try again.`

I am currently using the latest nativescript-cli.

Is it possible to debug a Mocha test in NativeScript with VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.5.0 of NativeScript CLI, the `watch` option is set to true by default. It looks like this breaks the `--debug-brk` option in `test` command. You can bypass it by setting the `watch` option to false. In order to achieve this just execute:

`$ tns test ios --debug-brk --no-watch`

Comment: Thank you! It did the trick. Unfortunately, the Nativescript inspector crashes 2 over 3 times. I was able to (very) briefly debug a test.